# PHP SQL Query ERROR in a select statement

Tags: php

```
$id = $_POST['idn'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xyz","patient");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM record WHERE ID='$id'";
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query($query),0);
if($count > '0')
{
id exist
}
else
{
add id & record 
}
```

whats the error here it does not check for if ID exists and adds duplicate id where ID is RC50001 RC50002...... ID defined as text in table

Comment: what is the value of $id ?

Comment: because e.g. 5 is not found (and your LIMIT is only nonsense, cause the query will - if ever - only return one row.)

Comment: What is the ***full error***? What is the result of `echo $query;`? Stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Is there a chance that there could be more than one RC50001 in the table? Usually when people say "ID" they're talking about a unique auto-incremental key field.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `LIKE`, use `=`, you are looking for an exact match against `ID` so `=` is the correct comparison operator to use in this case:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `record` WHERE `ID` = '$id' LIMIT 0 , 300";
```

And you should verify `$id` is in the format you are expecting before inserting it into a query.
Also, you should be using the [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) extensions rather than the `mysql` one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just checking to see if the ID has been used in the database, it will be more efficient just to return the number of times the ID has been used instead of returning every single matching record.

Note: this is using MySQLi due to the fact that the mysql_* functions will be deprecated in the next version of PHP to be released (already in beta). You will need to update all `mysql_*()` functions to `mysqli_*()`.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS IDCount FROM `record` WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute ID check query.");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['IDCount'] > 0)
{
    echo "ID already exists<br />";
}
```

Comment: Looks familiar. Since he's using mysql_query in his example this will break when he copies and pastes the code, although he \*should\* be using this or a PDO.

Comment: Haha, gotta love those overlapping posts!  :P  MySQLi is designed to be super easy to swap in for the older mysql_* functions... and they are all officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0!

Comment: I know, but you need to note that he'll have to update more code. Since he's not getting the results from his query there might be other issues.

Comment: Done. Amended to have a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

Have your code echo your query and then test it in something like MySQL workbench or PHPMyAdmin.

If you're looking for an ID it's going to be exact. You want to be careful using LIKE in your statements. Eg. If someone looks for id='1' it returns one record. id LIKE '%1%' returns all records containing a "1".

This is a lot safer. Especially since you aren't doing anything with the ID according to your example.

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM record WHERE ID='$id'";
  $count = mysql_result(mysql_query($query),0);
  if($count > '0'){
    echo "ID already exists<br>";
  } else {
    echo($query);        
    die();
  }  
?>
```

I've not tested it, but something like this *should* be used, or a MySQLi statement, but you'll need to learn the way to code in this style.

```
<?php
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
        $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM record WHERE ID='$id'";
                    //Checking for no results.
        if(!empty($dbh->query($query))){
          echo "ID already exists.";
        } else {
          echo "ID does not exist.";
        }  
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

?>
```

Oh yeah and remember:

> **Warning:** If your application does not catch the exception thrown from
>   the PDO constructor, the default action taken by the zend engine is to
>   terminate the script and display a back trace. This back trace will
>   likely reveal the full database connection details, including the
>   username and password. It is your responsibility to catch this
>   exception, either explicitly (via a catch statement) or implicitly via
>   set_exception_handler().

Answer (score 0):

i think u can rather use a while loop to search for the matching id in the database rather than just using the if-else statement alone.

sample :

```
if($row != 0)
{ 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
  {
     $row['id'];
  }
```